# Why does std::unique_ptr has a "get()" member function?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

Isn't `std::unique_ptr` designed to be an unique pointer to a memory, and no other pointer should point to this memory ?

Then why does `std:unique_ptr` has a `get()` member function which returns a raw pointer to the memory owned by the `std::unique_ptr` ?

So by using `get()` we can create numerous owners ( raw pointers ) to the `std::unique_ptr`'s memory, isn't that senseless ?

Comment: not raw pointers are owners.  It's only an owner if you say it is.

Comment: They have total control of the memory which they point, why they wouldn't be considered as owners ?

Comment: As long as you have placed the pointer to your allocated memory into a `std::unique_ptr` (at the correct scope) you can safely use the raw pointer (obtained with `get()`) throughout that scope knowing it will be deleted at the appropriate time.

Comment: @Galik Can't someone do `delete ptr.get()` before it goes out of scope?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Someone COULD do that. C++ allows people doing stuff they shouldn't do in many ways, so why should that particular stupidity be "not possible". As explained in my answer, there are things that you simply can't do without a `get` function.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Of course. But why would anyone do that?

Comment: These days IMHO the vast majority of the time C++ programmers should not be thinking in terms of deleting raw pointers. They should be thinking about where to place the creation of the smart pointer and which smart pointer is appropriate for the task in hand. Then you can enjoy the speed of the raw pointer safely knowing its lifetime is managed.

Comment: @user2591935: If a guy holds a gun to my head, he has pretty much total control over me at that point.  Doesn't mean he owns me or my stuff though.  Control does not imply ownership.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine that you do:

```
void process_file()
{
   const int max_size = 10000; 
   std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer(new char[max_size]); 

   ifstream f("myfile.txt"); 

   f.read(buffer.get(), max_size); 
   ... 
   ... process buffer
   ...
}
```

How would you do this without `get()`? `unique_ptr` can't be passed to `istream::read` as it is.

Well, as the comment says, you can do it by using `&*buffer`, but that is far from easy to follow - using `buffer.get()` clearly states to the reader that "this is the raw pointer inside the buffer.

Comment: "How would you do this without get()?" `&*buffer`

Comment: Exactly. The better answer is that having `get` allows you to make it clear that you're extracting a naked pointer from a unique pointer, rather than requiring people to figure it out from `&*` or from comments.